# Cannot run pool.amap() twice in pathos.multiprocessing

Tags: multiprocessing, pickle, pathos

I want to parallelize simulation of multiple agents. Because I want my results to be instances of a class, to avoid issues with serialization I use **pathos.multiprocessing** instead of **multiprocessing**.

I do it like this:

```
import pathos.multiprocessing as mp

sim_agent(T): #simulate single agent for T periods 
    ag = agent()
    for t in range(T):
         ag.step()   
    return ag

def simulate_parallel(N, T):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pool = mp.ProcessPool()
        results = pool.amap(sim_agent, [T]*N)
        agents = results.get()
        return agents
```

I can run **simulate_parallel** once. When I do it again, I get an error:

```
--> 142         agents = results.get()

~/anaconda3/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    655             return self._value
    656         else:
--> 657             raise self._value
    658 
    659     def _set(self, i, obj):

~/anaconda3/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py in _handle_tasks(taskqueue, put, outqueue, pool, cache)
    429                         break
    430                     try:
--> 431                         put(task)
    432                     except Exception as e:
    433                         job, idx = task[:2]

~/anaconda3/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/multiprocess/connection.py in send(self, obj)
    207         self._check_closed()
    208         self._check_writable()
--> 209         self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
    210 
    211     def recv_bytes(self, maxlength=None):

~/anaconda3/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/multiprocess/connection.py in _send_bytes(self, buf)
    394         n = len(buf)
    395         # For wire compatibility with 3.2 and lower
--> 396         header = struct.pack("!i", n)
    397         if n > 16384:
    398             # The payload is large so Nagle's algorithm won't be triggered

error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```

I also get the same error when I try to use **pool.amap()** in other functions. Even when I make N and T small, it is still the same behavior: I can run **simulate_parallel** once and cannot do it for the second time. Why could that be? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm the `pathos` author.  This may be better handled by submitting an issue on `pathos` GitHub.  It would help to (1) have a minimal code that can reproduce the issue, and (2) know what versions of pathos and python you are using, and also what is your OS.

Comment: I'm not seeing the behavior your describe when I tested it, using python 3.6.14, pathos 0.2.9.dev0, on a Mac.  Everything works as expected.  I encourage you to do (1) and (2) in the comment above.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I will submit it on GitHub soon. It might be a bit hard to provide a minimal code, but I will do my best.